# Changing color of bootstrap "well" on mouseover

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to change the color of "well" on mouseover but unable to do it. I have been trying with the following codes:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ChangeColor(well, highLight)
    {
    if (highLight)
    {
      well.style.backgroundColor = '#dcfac9';
    }
         }
</script>
PHP:

echo "  <div class=\"well\" onmouseover=\"ChangeColor(this, true);\"\n"; 
echo " onmouseout=\"ChangeColor(this, false);\"> \n"; 
echo "something";
echo "  </div>\n";
```

The above code is changing color nicely on mouseover but it is crossing the area of the "well". Please help to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet"  href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>


<div class="well">
  <p>
     This is a well content
   </p>
</div>


<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(".well").mouseenter(
    function(){
      $(this).css('background-color','red');
    });
  
   $(".well").mouseleave(
    function(){
      $(this).css('background-color','#f5f5f5');
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Doing this through JavaScript seems like overkill.  This can easily be done simply through the use of CSS:

```css
.well:default
{
  background-color: #ccc;
}
.well:hover
{
  background-color: #000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var getDefaultBg    = $(".well").css("background");
$(".well").mouseover(function() {
    $(this).css("background", "#000");
}). mouseout(function() {
    $(this).css("background", getDefaultBg);
});
```

simply use this for your requirement.

Comment: Thanks. But I want to keep the original color of "well" unchanged on mouseout.

Comment: use just css then, use .well:hover { background: changeColor; }

Answer (score 0):

That was the script I wanted:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".well").mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).css("background-color", "#efefef");
    });
    $(".well").mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).css("background-color", "#f5f5f5");
    });
});
</script>
```